# Stack Overflow for Teams support

Tags: support, api, api-key, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am reading this documentation https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385859-stack-overflow-for-teams-api where they mention the need to create a PAT to access StackOverflow for Teams API (https://api.stackoverflowteams.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&team=Crew&run=true)

But in my current Settings page of Stack Overflow for Teams all I can see is: [image: Stack Overflow for Teams Settings]

It looks like I am not able to generate a new PAT. Is it a problem or am I missing something? How can I access the new StackOverflow for Teams Api?

Comment: I have another item under the 'API' section with Personal Access Tokens. I assume this is dependent on the Team's [plan](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/pricing). Perhaps staff can confirm whether the API will still be working for the Free tier?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Glorfindel, do you know if there is any option to test the api with a free/new stack overflow for teams plan?

Comment: I only have experience with the [old way](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) - that works/worked on all Teams instances.

Comment: Are you an admin on any of your teams?

Comment: I made a team for testing the new API, so I am the only user and admin of the team!

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the Free Tier Stack Overflow Team does not have access to APIs. You will not be able to create a PAT if you only have a Free Tier Team assigned to your account.

Comment: thank you for your response! so i guess there is no way to test the new api, am i correct?

Comment: Correct. It only is accessible to those with paid subscriptions.